# Why payment status is completed even email is not registered in paypal

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments

If receiver email is not registered in paypal.
after sending payment, receiver register this email on paypal (sandbox) then showing previous payment status - "Completed"
but in payment response, paymentInfoList is null (transactionStatus is not completed). 
If receiver email is not registered then payment status should not be "completed".

Please provide me solution for this problem.

For example - 
Payment Response (if email is not registered in paypal-sandbox ) :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [responseEnvelope] => stdClass Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 2013-10-22T05:26:42.879-07:00
            [ack] => Success
            [correlationId] => ff84129c35f8f
            [build] => 7935900
        )

    [payKey] => AP-3JH92245KM002970K
    [paymentExecStatus] => COMPLETED
    [paymentInfoList] => 
    [sender] => stdClass Object
        (
            [accountId] => Q32USVKHWLSMU
        )

)
```